# How to pass a double quoted string to a function that executes as sudo

Tags: command-line, bash, package-management, scripts, repository

I am trying to create a script that will add regular apt repositories `deb http://repo.tld/ubuntu distro component` listed in a file.

I got a function that checks for sudo status to make sure the command is run as sudo.

```bsh
superdo() {
    # do some checks and prompt user for password if he is not logged in as sudo
    # execute the command passed in as an argument
    sudo $@
}
```

This is the function that reads the repos from a list that looks like this:

```
#package-name|key|"repo"
vscode|https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc|"deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main"
```

The functions:

```bsh
# ${1} = list-name
# ${2} = https://key.example.com/signing-key-pub.gpg
# ${3} = "deb https://repo.example.com/linux apt/repo"
add_apt_repo() {
    # Check if repo already exists
    if ! grep -q "${3}" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; then
        superdo "apt-key adv --fetch-keys ${2}"
        superdo "add-apt-repository -y ${3}"
    else
        echo "${1} repository already exists."
    fi
}
list="path_to_list_file"
while read line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    # skip commented lines.
    [[ $line = \#* ]] && continue
    IFS='|' read package key repo <<< $line
    add_apt_repo "$package" "$key" "$repo"
done <"$list"
```

I am having two problems here:

1. the script doesn't grep for the repo properly, so it always ends up trying to re-add the repository.
2. the `repository` variable is not passed with its quotes to the `$@` in the `superdo` function, so I always end up with the following error:

```bsh
Error: need a single repository as argument
```

I have tried `set -x` to see how the command is executed and I get the following:

```bsh
+ sudo add-apt-repository -y '"deb' http://www.scootersoftware.com/ bcompare4 'non-free"'
```

Comment: If you want the individual positional parameters to be shell-quoted (which you almost always do), use `"$@"` rather than the unquoted `$@` - see the `Special Parameters` subsection of `man bash`

Comment: @steeldriver If I use `"$@` the command passed to sudo ends up being quoted, so sudo tries to execute `'add-apt-repository -y <repo>'` (its a string) instead of `add-apt-repository -y '<repo>'`, so I end with `command not found`.

Comment: OK I just noticed you are doing `superdo "apt-key adv --fetch-keys ${2}"` inside your function - you should pass the individual arguments there, i.e. `superdo apt-key adv --fetch-keys "${2}"`

Comment: @steeldriver the problem is with the second execution, `apt-key adv .....` works without any problems, its `add-apt-repository -y <repo>` that doesn't work. I tried unquoting the command like you said as follows `superdo add-apt-repository -y "${3}"` but I still get the same error `Error: need a single repository as argument`
this is the result of set -x `+ sudo add-apt-repository -y '"deb' http://www.scootersoftware.com/ bcompare4 'non-free"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to preserve the `$3` value as a single string, not split on spaces. To start with, as steeldriver says in the comments, you must use

```bsh
sudo "$@"
```

and that means you must call

```
superdo apt-key adv --fetch-keys "${2}"
superdo add-apt-repository -y "${3}"
```

The problem you find is that you end up with `add-apt-repository` then being passed a string that includes the double-quotes from the file. You need to remove these. For example, after the `IFS=... read` add

```
repo=${repo//\"}
```

Finally, replace `grep` by `fgrep` to avoid the interpretation of `[]` in the string as a pattern.